# crtexe.c SFML 2.0 crash after main returns

Tags: c++, opengl, fixed, sfml

> ***I have resolved this issue***. 
>   I was running a program called RadeonPro, which is a graphics card manager tool. When I changed my graphics card I forgot to update that program. I have since removed RadeonPro and now my program terminates correctly!
>
> I would guess that anyone with a similar problem can fix this by removing/updating any programs that might be using the problematic library (for me it was atioglxx.dll)

It has been a while since I have looked at this project, since then I have gotten a new graphics card (my drivers are up to date).

The problem is that when I exit my program it causes a break (inside a debugger) or a crash if I launch normally. The crash occurs after the main function returns and happens on the function call marked below in crtexe.c.

```
/*
 * Note that if the exe is managed app, we don't really need to
 * call exit or _c_exit. .cctor should be able to take care of
 * this.
 */
 if ( !managedapp )
      exit(mainret);  //<<< This Line

 if (has_cctor == 0)
       _cexit();
```

By trial and error (commenting out blocks of code) I have narrowed the problem line in my own code to this:

```
mRenderWindow->display();
```

mRenderWindow is an [SFML RenderWindow](http://sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.0/classsf_1_1Window.php), I am using 2.0 but considering updating to 2.1. Anyway, when I remove that line the program exits normally.

The reason I mentioned my graphics initially is because when the crash occurs my stack trace has this at the top:

```
atioglxx.dll!03fc0054()
```

Which is, if I am not mistaken, an ATi OpenGL related dll.

I have been looking around and seen several posts on different forums with the same issue but no solutions. Hopefully somebody can shed some light on this issue for me!

Comment: `mRenderWindow` appears to be not an SFML RenderWindow, but a pointer to one.  Are you sure the pointer is valid?  If you change the statement to -- `if (mRenderWindow) { mRenderWindow->display(); }` -- Does it still crash?

Comment: The program itself runs fine, it draws to the screen correctly and it will never call display() if mRenderWindow is invalid because of earlier checks. It is only when I terminate the application, after main returns, that the problem occurs.